# Unable to find crate when compiling even after successfully running `cargo build`

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I've been trying to compile a project written in Rust.  When I first compiled, I got the error

```
error[E0463]: can't find crate for `argparse`
 --> src/main.rs:6:1
  |
6 | extern crate argparse;
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ can't find crate
```

This seemed like a dependency error meaning that I needed to use Cargo. Luckily, the project provided a `Cargo.toml` file for me to use.  I ran `cargo build` successfully and attempted to compile the Rust source again.

The error persisted so I opened up the `Cargo.toml` to take a look.  It contained what I would have expected

```
[package]
name = "stones"
version = "0.5.0"
authors = ["cheezgi <zackh@firemail.cc>"]

[dependencies]
argparse = "*"
rustyline = "*"

[profile.dev]
debug = true
```

I ran `cargo build -v` to make sure everything was going as expected.

```
       Fresh unicode-width v0.1.4
       Fresh bitflags v0.4.0
       Fresh libc v0.2.20
       Fresh argparse v0.2.1
       Fresh encode_unicode v0.1.3
       Fresh nix v0.5.1
       Fresh rustyline v1.0.0
       Fresh stones v0.5.0 (file:///Users/eamonolive/projects/stones)
    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.0 secs
```

I couldn't see anything wrong with the results here, it looked like everything was installed properly but the compiler continues to be unable to find the crate for argparse.

I'm using rustc 1.19.0 if it makes any difference.

Comment: *Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.0 secs* — that's your project compiling successfully. **There is no error**.

Comment: @Shepmaster There is still an error when compiling.  Cargo doesn't error but the compiler does.

Comment: `cargo build` *runs the compiler* and reports no errors. I don't understand how you are getting an error outside of that

Comment: @Shepmaster Ah I did not know that.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I ran cargo build successfully and attempted to compile the Rust source again.

Cargo runs the compiler for you. By calling `cargo build`, you have already implicitly called the compiler (`rustc`) and the program is built and ready to be executed: `cargo run` or `./target/debug/my-app-name`.

It's a very rare occurrence to call `rustc` directly.